# In Office365 Desktop add-ins, office.js file not being loaded inside html that open inside the Dialog

Tags: office365, office-js, office365-apps

In online Office365 add-ins, I am able to achieve the SSO
But when I am trying to do the same in Offline Office365 desktop application, I am facing a problem because I am not able to load the js file in the HTML page that opened inside the Dialog by Office365 Add-in

```
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
    `${window.location.origin}/o365-redirect`, {
        height: 30,
        width: 30
    },
    asyncResult => {
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        `enter code here`
        dialog.addEventHandler(
            Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived,
            processMessage
        );
        setTimeout(() => {
            if (!getResults && dialog) {
                dialog.close();
                this.setState({
                    showSSOError: true
                });
            }
        }, 30000);
    }
);
```

Below is the HTML that is being shown inside the dialog that is opened using above code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <style>
        p {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div>
        <p class="ms-font-m" id="info">Please wait for this window to close, before continuing with the add-in.</p>
    </div>

    <script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/office.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        Office.initialize = () => {
            const ssoLink = localStorage.getItem("ssoLink");

            if (ssoLink) {
                localStorage.removeItem("ssoLink");
                document.location.href = `${ssoLink}`;
            } else {
                let messageObject = {};
                let link = document.location.search.substring(1).split('&');

                link.forEach(el => {
                    let param = el.split('=');
                    messageObject[param[0]] = param[1]
                });
                let jsonMessage = JSON.stringify(messageObject);
                Office.context.ui.messageParent(jsonMessage);
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

JS file loads perfectly when I open my add-in in online Office365 but failed to load when I use this add-in in Office365 desktop application.

Please help me guys, getting blocked here.

Comment: What symptoms tell you that Office.js has not loaded? Also, in your callback to `displayDialogAsync`, please read the `asyncResult.status` and `asyncResult.error` properties. There is an example of doing this at: [AsyncResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/office/office.asyncresult?view=office-js)

Comment: I confirmed that Office.js is not being loaded by giving an id to the <p> tag and trying to replace the text by using document.getElementById().innerHTML="given text" inside the Office.initialize function and text does not get changed in case of Office desktop App

Comment: So, you do not get an error saying that Office is undefined? Also please add the error checking I suggested.

Comment: @RickKirkham - I have added the error checking and nothing happened.
Even if I use document.getElementById().innerHTML='some text' a line before the function Office.initialize still the text is not get changed, So, we can say that Js does not support in Dialog window of Desktop Office365 Application.
Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: JS is supported in dialogs created with `displayDialogAsync`. But you need to pass a parameter to `getElementById()`. See [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById).

Answer (score 0):

Some of the important bits for your reading

> Office Add-ins are secured by an add-in runtime environment, a
>   multiple-tier permissions model, and performance governors. This
>   framework protects the user's experience in the following ways:

1. Access to the host application's UI frame is managed.
2. Only indirect access to the host application's UI thread is allowed.
3. Modal interactions aren't allowed - **for example, calls to JavaScript alert, confirm, and prompt functions aren't allowed because they're modal**.

please see the official link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/concepts/privacy-and-security

You will get the error if you are redirecting inside the taskpane

[image]

You can redo that in many different ways

1. Pick a framework like Angular, React using Yeoman Generator office. Link below

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/project-quickstart

2. Instead of dialog use the Tabs or new component which can redirect and get the token.
3. sometimes cards or accordion will help you to achieve that.

The above is how I have achieved some web addins successfully. Hope it helps you in some way and give some clear idea on how to proceed further.